# Programmatically created UIButton go to other VC, Swift

Tags: swift

I created a UIButton programmatically. How can I make it so that it will show the next View Controller? I want it to pretty much do the exact same thing it does when you Control -> drag -> Modal to next View Controller when you create the button in the storyboard.

This is my code so far.

```
let clickButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

func clickPressed (sender: UIButton!) {
    //Presenting next View Controller happens here?        
}

func createClickButton () {    
    clickButton.frame = CGRect(x: 80 / 320 * view.frame.width,
        y: 204 / 568 * view.frame.height,
            width: 160 / 320 * view.frame.width,
                height: 160 / 568 * view.frame.height)
    if let clickImage = UIImage(named: "click") {
        clickButton.setImage(clickImage, forState: .Normal)
        clickButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    }

    clickButton.addTarget(self, action: "clickPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    clickButton.addTarget(self, action: "clickPressedUp:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(clickButton)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createClickButton()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presentViewController(/*your view cntr here*/, animated: true, completion: nil)`

for example, I have a RecipeViewController. Make sure this view controller is tagged with a Storyboard ID. You can do this in the identity inspector (cmd + alt + 3). My Storyboard ID for this view controller is "RecipeViewController".

```
let recipeViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RecipeViewController") as RecipeViewController
presentViewController(recipeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin ! Appreciate it a lot !

Comment: For some reason it's giving me a exc bad instruction on the target view controller. I did exactly like you described and gives this error -> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @MilesH.

I apologize for my mistake. You cannot simply make a view controller by doing `let controller = Controller()`.  I've corrected my response accordingly (and tested it).